# Share mountnamespce between container

Tags: docker

Is it possible to share the same mount namespace between containers?

I'm interested to mount something in container A and be able to access the mount point on container B.

Comment: Not sure if I understand your question correctly. Are you looking for [`--volumes-from`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/dockervolumes/#creating-and-mounting-a-data-volume-container)?

Comment: Actually not. I need a container to mount inside a share. And a second container to share the same mount namespace (?), so to have access to the same mount point.

Answer (score 0):

If you have defined that "something" as a **data volume container**, then you can [create it and mount it](https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/dockervolumes/#creating-and-mounting-a-data-volume-container) in as many container as you need.

> If you have some persistent data that you want to share between containers, or want to use from non-persistent containers, it’s best to create a named Data Volume Container, and then to mount the data from it.
>
> Let’s create a new named container with a volume to share. While this container doesn’t run an application, it reuses the `training/postgres` image so that all containers are using layers in common, saving disk space.

```
$ docker create -v /dbdata --name dbdata training/postgres /bin/true
```

> You can then use the `--volumes-from` flag to mount the `/dbdata` volume in another container.

```
$ docker run -d --volumes-from dbdata --name db1 training/postgres
```

> And another:

```
$ docker run -d --volumes-from dbdata --name db2 training/postgres
```